# Why does strace show that syscall =?

Tags: linux, kernel, c, system-calls, strace

I made a system call and recompiled the kernel, however upon running the system call it returned Killed. So, to trace it, I used strace, which shows the following message:
`syscall_0x224(0x7ffda7199738, 0x7ffda7199748, 0x55743750a6d0, 0x7f9f20df7d80, 0x7f9f20df7d80, 0x7ffda7199730) = ?`

What does this mean (not the hex, the question mark)?

Answer (score 5):

It means that the system call was terminated, and didn't (couldn't) return a value. An example is given in [the `strace` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html):

```
Interruption of a (restartable) system call by a signal delivery is
processed differently as kernel terminates the system call and also
arranges its immediate reexecution after the signal handler
completes.

   read(0, 0x7ffff72cf5cf, 1)     = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
```

It seems, like your system call, `read` here was terminated, and has no return value. (Unlike your system call, `read` here was scheduled for re-execution.)

Other system calls, which don't return (e.g., `exit_group`), also show `?`:

```
~ strace -e exit_group /bin/true
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 3):

This means that your `strace` doesn't know about `syscall_0x224` (neither do I [1]), and doesn't know what kind of value returns and how to decode it.

You can have a look at the source [here](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/480825af3b5303ce99d398a9ef47546f2f383411/syscall.c#L851):

```
        if (sys_res & RVAL_NONE)
                tprints("= ?");
```

If you have compiled some module that adds another system call, do **not** expect strace to magically know about it.

[1] I wasn't able to find any syscall with nr = 0x224 / 548 (the [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) `pwritev2` is the last = 547).

Comment: They said they "made a system call", so that's probably why no-one has heard about it :)